# passing fstream as argument

Tags: c++, file, stream, fstream

I cant pass `fstream` as an argument to a function

Like `fname(fstream , char []); /* Prototype */`

and call `fname(fs, p);`

it throws error,

```
In copy constructor ‘std::basic_ios<char>::basic_ios(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:786:5: error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);
```

I later learned that i have to use `fstream&`. I am just wondering does streams are treated differently than objects ? if yes can someone just tell some proper source of reading so that I don't mess up again.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Error says

`error: ‘std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
     ios_base(const ios_base&);`,

fstream does not have a copy constructor (The copy constructor is defined as private). You need to pass the `fstream` object by `reference` rather than by `value`.

This would effectively mean, your prototype signature needs to be changed

```
fname(fstream& , char []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Stream object is not copiable. What should happen in your copying stream which, say, associated with a file?